# Crash when using SafeMailItem (fault in mso20win32client.dll)

Tags: outlook, vb6, outlook-redemption, office-automation

We use Redemption since many years.  Since few days many of our clients have issues when they use our plugin for Outlook.  We changed nothing in our app.

I did some traces and found that the line `Set CourielOutlook = New Redemption.SafeMailItem` makes the app to crash.  Events viewer show that the fault is in `mso20win32client.dll`.

I tried to find the problem by create a simple app doing the same thing and there is no problem with this one!!?

I found that if I rename the original app with a new name (`AddinOutlook.exe` to `AddinOutlook2.exe`), *the app doesn't crash anymore*!

If I rename my simple app to `AddinOutlook.exe`, it crashes!

I tried many things in Outlook (deleting and recreating the profile, deleting and recreating the account, uninstall and reinstall Office 365).  The problem still there.

After deleting and recreating the profile, it works the first time, but after that never (except if I rename the exe).

Any idea?

Here is my simple test app:

```
   Dim Outlook As Outlook.Application

   Dim Item As Object

   Dim Namespace As Object

   Dim CourielOutlook As Object 'Redemption.SafeMailItem


   Set Outlook = New Outlook.Application

   If Not Outlook Is Nothing Then

      On Error Resume Next

      Err.Clear

      Set Namespace = Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

      If Err.Number <> 0 Then

         Call Namespace.Logon(vbNullString, vbNullString, False)

      End If

      If Err.Number = 0 Then

         If TypeName(Outlook.ActiveWindow) = "Inspector" Then

            Call AjouterElement(Outlook.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem)

            Set CourielOutlook = New Redemption.SafeMailItem

            CourielOutlook.Item = Outlook.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem

            '...

         ElseIf TypeName(Outlook.ActiveWindow) = "Explorer" Then

            For Each Item In Outlook.ActiveExplorer.Selection

               Set CourielOutlook = New Redemption.SafeMailItem

               CourielOutlook.Item = Item

               '...

            Next

         End If

      End If

   End If

   
   Set Outlook = Nothing
```

Comment: Please send a message to redemption (at) dimastr (dot) com, and I will send you the debug version of Redemption.

Comment: What Redemption version are you using? Can you share the results after sending the debug logs with others?

Comment: Have you gotten anywhere with your investigation? Is it positively true that renaming the executable helps?